# How to (re)name an empty column header in a pandas dataframe without exporting to csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, rename

I have a pandas dataframe `df1` with an index column and an unnamed series of values. I want to assign a name to the unnamed series.

The only way to do this that I know so far is to export to `df1.csv` using:

`df1.to_csv("df1.csv", header = ["Signal"])`

and then re-import using:

`pd.read_csv("df1.csv", sep=",")`

However, this costs time and storage space. How to do this in-memory?

When I do `df2 = df1.rename(columns = {"" : "Signal"}, inplace = True)`

I yield:

`AttributeError: "Series" object has no attribute "Signal"`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think `inplace=True` has to be removed, because it return `None`:

```
df2 = df1.rename(columns = {"" : "Signal"})
```

---

```
df1.rename(columns = {"" : "Signal"}, inplace = True)
```

Another solution is asign new name by position:

```
df.columns.values[0] = 'Signal'
```

Sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

print (df1)
      B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9

df2 = df1.rename(columns = {"" : "Signal"})
print (df2)
   Signal  B  C
0       1  4  7
1       2  5  8
2       3  6  9
```

Comment: This is a simplistic solution to when there is only one single unnamed column. What is the solution when there are more than one column without a name? How do you rename them?

Comment: @VictorCallegari - Then simpliest is set new columns name by list  like `df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4']`.

Comment: I guess I could do that for now since I am dealing with less than 10 columns. But I wonder how do you handle it when you have a lot of columns where listing all of them seems to be odd.

Comment: @VictorCallegari - then solution should be create list of columns like `L = df.columns.tolist()`, then processing list like you need, e.g. `L[0]` = 'col4', `L[5] = 'col5'` and last assign back like `df.columns = L`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this if there are multiple empty columns. This will generate an empty column with **cols** and **i** (for the column position)

```
df.columns = ["cols_"+str(i) if a == "" else a for i, a in enumerate(df.columns)]

#cols -> just rename the column name just as you want
#i -> count the column number
```